# About Google Campaigns

Tags: html, google-analytics, analytics, campaign-monitor

After reviewing my Google analytics document, I have found the solution to the discrepancy in traffic between reports.
It is because 50% of our campaign was going to one site and 50% to another site which is having same campaign.

Two different creatives going to two different sites.

My question is will two different sites has same URL builders like *utm_source*, *utm_medium*, *utm_campaign*.
     How do I trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about what are you saying, you can use utm_term or utm_content to make it separate. Can you describe more about your situation . URL Builder: 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en